# How can I get a week number in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've tried this but it returns `text15 = 09/12/2020 Result = 2eek`, I actually need `week 2`.

```
=Format(DatePart("ww",[Text15])-DatePart("ww",DateSerial(Year([Text15]),Month([Text15]),1))+1,"Week ")
```

Comment: So you need the week of the month?

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, try this:

```
= "Week " & (DatePart("ww",[Text15])-DatePart("ww",DateSerial(Year([Text15]),Month([Text15]),1))) + 1
```

or this:

```
="Week " & Abs(Int(-DatePart("d",[Text15])/7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method similar to the ISO 8601 numbering of weeks:

```vb
' Calculates the "weeknumber of the month" for a date.
' The value will be between 1 and 5.
'
' Numbering is similar to the ISO 8601 numbering having Monday
' as the first day of the week and the first week beginning
' with Thursday or later as week number 1.
' Thus, the first day of a month may belong to the last week
' of the previous month, having a week number of 4 or 5.
'
' 2020-09-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function WeekOfMonth( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date) _
    As Integer
    
    Dim ThursdayInWeek  As Date
    Dim FirstThursday   As Date
    Dim WeekNumber      As Integer
    
    ThursdayInWeek = DateWeekdayInWeek(Date1, vbThursday, vbMonday)
    FirstThursday = DateWeekdayInMonth(ThursdayInWeek, 1, vbThursday)
    WeekNumber = 1 + DateDiff("ww", FirstThursday, Date1, vbMonday)
    
    WeekOfMonth = WeekNumber
    
End Function
```

As you can see, a supporting function is used:

```vb
Option Explicit

    Public Const DaysPerWeek            As Long = 7
    Public Const MaxWeekdayCountInMonth As Integer = 5

' Calculates the "weeknumber of the month" for a date.
' The value will be between 1 and 5.
'
' Numbering is similar to the ISO 8601 numbering having Monday
' as the first day of the week and the first week beginning
' with Thursday or later as week number 1.
' Thus, the first day of a month may belong to the last week
' of the previous month, having a week number of 4 or 5.
'
' 2020-09-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function WeekOfMonth( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date) _
    As Integer
    
    Dim ThursdayInWeek  As Date
    Dim FirstThursday   As Date
    Dim WeekNumber      As Integer
    
    ThursdayInWeek = DateWeekdayInWeek(Date1, vbThursday)
    FirstThursday = DateWeekdayInMonth(ThursdayInWeek, 1, vbThursday)
    WeekNumber = 1 + DateDiff("ww", FirstThursday, Date1, vbMonday)
    
    WeekOfMonth = WeekNumber
    
End Function


' Calculates the date of DayOfWeek in the week of DateInWeek.
' By default, the returned date is the first day in the week
' as defined by the current Windows settings.
'
' Optionally, parameter DayOfWeek can be specified to return
' any other weekday of the week.
' Further, parameter FirstDayOfWeek can be specified to select
' any other weekday as the first weekday of a week.
'
' Limitation:
' For the first and the last week of the range of Date, some
' combinations of DayOfWeek and FirstDayOfWeek that would result
' in dates outside the range of Date, will raise an overflow error.
'
' 2017-05-03. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInWeek( _
    ByVal DateInWeek As Date, _
    Optional ByVal DayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    Optional ByVal FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
    As Date
    
    Dim DayInWeek   As VbDayOfWeek
    Dim OffsetZero  As Integer
    Dim OffsetFind  As Integer
    Dim ResultDate  As Date
    
    ' Find the date of DayOfWeek.
    DayInWeek = Weekday(DateInWeek)
    ' Find the offset of the weekday of DateInWeek from the first day of the week.
    ' Will always be <= 0.
    OffsetZero = (FirstDayOfWeek - DayInWeek - DaysPerWeek) Mod DaysPerWeek
    ' Find the offset of DayOfWeek from the first day of the week.
    ' Will always be >= 0.
    OffsetFind = (DayOfWeek - FirstDayOfWeek + DaysPerWeek) Mod DaysPerWeek
    ' Calculate result date using the sum of the offset parts.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", OffsetZero + OffsetFind, DateInWeek)
    
    DateWeekdayInWeek = ResultDate
  
End Function


' Calculates the date of the occurrence of Weekday in the month of DateInMonth.
'
' If Occurrence is 0 or negative, the first occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
' If Occurrence is 5 or larger, the last occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
'
' If Weekday is invalid or not specified, the weekday of DateInMonth is used.
'
' 2019-12-08. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInMonth( _
    ByVal DateInMonth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Occurrence As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Weekday As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
    As Date
    
    Dim Offset          As Integer
    Dim Month           As Integer
    Dim Year            As Integer
    Dim ResultDate      As Date
    
    ' Validate Weekday.
    Select Case Weekday
        Case _
            vbMonday, _
            vbTuesday, _
            vbWednesday, _
            vbThursday, _
            vbFriday, _
            vbSaturday, _
            vbSunday
        Case Else
            ' vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, zero, none or invalid value for VbDayOfWeek.
            Weekday = VBA.Weekday(DateInMonth)
    End Select
    
    ' Validate Occurence.
    If Occurrence < 1 Then
        ' Find first occurrence.
        Occurrence = 1
    ElseIf Occurrence > MaxWeekdayCountInMonth Then
        ' Find last occurrence.
        Occurrence = MaxWeekdayCountInMonth
    End If
    
    ' Start date.
    Month = VBA.Month(DateInMonth)
    Year = VBA.Year(DateInMonth)
    ResultDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)
    
    ' Find offset of Weekday from first day of month.
    Offset = DaysPerWeek * (Occurrence - 1) + (Weekday - VBA.Weekday(ResultDate) + DaysPerWeek) Mod DaysPerWeek
    ' Calculate result date.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, ResultDate)
    
    If Occurrence = MaxWeekdayCountInMonth Then
        ' The latest occurrency of Weekday is requested.
        ' Check if there really is a fifth occurrence of Weekday in this month.
        If VBA.Month(ResultDate) <> Month Then
            ' There are only four occurrencies of Weekday in this month.
            ' Return the fourth as the latest.
            ResultDate = DateAdd("d", -DaysPerWeek, ResultDate)
        End If
    End If
    
    DateWeekdayInMonth = ResultDate
  
End Function
```

Watch an example output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029314/3527297).